# Get json data from drag and drop components

Tags: angular, typescript

how to get data from *ngFor loop, where I call data from another component.

[Take a look at a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9kjw6-7e72tu?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts).

I need to create JSON from selected forms controls and values in `DROP` place, JSONexample

```
questions = [{
    type: "INPUT",
    value: "test"
}, {
    type: "SELECT_BOX",
    selectedValue: "select option 1",
    avaliableOptions: ["select option 1", "select option 2", "select option 3"]
}]
```

Sry, if JSON format is not ok, this is onl yfor example

in component cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example I want data from FORM div.... user create custom questions, and on save I need to store selected questions, selected answer and also, all options (in the select box, checkbox...., because in future, the user will add manually all options in this questions

Comment: which data you want in which component?

Comment: in component `cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example` i want data from `FORM` div.... user create custom questions, and on save I need to store selected questions, selected answer and also, all options (in select box, check box...., because in future, user will add manually all options in this questions )

Comment: @Arter is that possible that your form can have same type of multiple controls ?

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil yes, it is... thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code for two controls, you can add more as your requirement. I have used **EventEmitter()** to get changed values of control as given below

```
@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();
```

please click [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-colntrols) to view all code.

you will get all of your items in **formitems** array

Comment: @Arter you can comment here to ask anything if you want to clarify the code..

Comment: @Alter Did this help you?

Comment: Hi, thnx... in monday i will see your answer, now I'm on road trip.. also, when I click on ur link, i get 404

Comment: I quickly chek it on my phone and I think this is exactly what I need... I will see it again on monday and accept ur answer...thnx bro you save me

Comment: in your example, I can not add multiple `INPUT` , only first working every another is empty

Comment: i have coded for two controls. Input and Select, you need to code the same logic for others..

Comment: can you pls help me, I can not get checkbox to work. For radio btn everything is working.... Here is example  - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-colntrols-rn57tj?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts

Comment: ok, the problem is **[(ngModel)]="val"** in **mat-checkbox** you can not assign same object to multiple controls. in your situation all three checkboxes have same reference. so, when you change one it  applied to  all. you need to remove this **[(ngModel)]="val"** and try diffrent logic. i am in office right now.. can't spent time on this :-(